# "(split, divide, separate) sth into adj. and adj.": is it grammatical or just omissive?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

The example sentence below is an excerpt from M. A. K. Halliday's *Linguistics as Metaphor*:

> [...] each discipline has tended to fragment into separate "branches"; linguistics, apart from its traditional **split into historical and descriptive**, held together until fairly late, but it too has now become a collection of specializations.

Since there is no information on this kind of usage in the *into* entry in OED, this seems to me like an omission (of the word *linguistics*) for good reason, so I searched Linggle:

> Firms are **divided into large and small** based on median total assets.
>
> The result would be a two-tiered society **divided into rich and poor**.
>
> A **division of the world into left and right** that is equally inapplicable to the past and to the present deserves to be discarded.
>
> I think we could **divide up the section 502 money into new and existing**, using 60 percent for ...
>
> Sensations are commonly **classified into internal and external**, but the meaning given to internal sensations today is not the same as formerly.

And there are some sentences with adjectives that are more frequently used as nouns even without a preceding "the", about which I'm less certain that they are in the same vein with the initial example:

> In the four-field matrix, the intensity of cooperation and competition is **divided into low and high**, while in the nine-field matrix is **split into low, medium, and high**.
> The sonnets differ in that the focus turns in the first poem to individual reactions to death, **dividing people into good and bad**.

Is this kind of usages naive omissions for brevity's sake, or is it under a particular grammatical category of its own right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "naive", but yes, the nouns in all the cases you found are elided for the sake of brevity. There's no special grammatical category here.

Comment: @gotube It seems that a more fitting wording here should be "pure and simple" instead of "naive". Thanks for your elucidation on both points.

Comment: Yes, in that case, they're pure and simple elisions.

Comment: I suggest this question to be migrated to english.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mephisto This seems to me perfectly appropriate here, and not in need of migration.

Comment: The technical term for deleting repeated material in conjoined constituents is [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299), and it's extremely common in English. And in most other languages, in some fashion.

Answer (score 1):

> ... linguistics, apart from its traditional **split into historical and descriptive**, held together until fairly late, but it too has now become a collection of specializations.

The phrase "*split into **historical** and **descriptive***" is a shortened form of "*split into **historical linguistics** and **descriptive linguistics***". Such an omission of a repeated noun, leaving  modifiers to stand as if they were nouns, when the sense is reasonably clear, is very common in English. It is not limited to a particular construction or situation. It is one of the ways in which adjectives and adverbs can come to be used as independent nouns. It is not specific with the construction "*{X} is divided into {A} and {B}*" although it can indeed be (and often is) used with that construction.

Some examples would be:

> - We tend to discuss sounds as either loud or soft. [short for "*loud sounds or soft sounds*".]
> - A programming  language can be both functional and declarative. [Derived from  "*functional programming*"and "*declarative programming*".]
> - People speak of fortunes as being composed of either new or old money. [Short for  "*new money or old money*". ]
> - Some will divide the population into tall and short. [Short for "*tall people and short people*".]
> - My insurance covers me for both inpatient and outpatient. [Omitting "procedures" or "visits" after "inpatient" and "outpatient".]
> - In the story of *Aladdin* the evil magician calls out "New lamps for old." [Short for "old lamps".]